# Does a Creality Ender 3 V2 running mriscoc firmware require a micro SD card at all?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, microsd, mriscoc, eeprom

To my understanding, all settings including those that resulted from the Nozzle Auto MPC tuning and Bed PID tuning and the created UBL mesh are all stored I the EEPROM by the mriscoc Marlin firmware on a Creality Ender 3 V2.

I'm asking because I recently encountered a bad (or very slow) micro SD card, where the printer took long to boot to the start screen and start beep (30 sec), consistently with a bad SD, and without a SD it booted almost instantly.

So, does a Creality Ender 3 V2 running mriscoc firmware require a micro SD card at all, for other things as I previously mentioned?

I'm printing only over USB using OctoPrint on a Raspberry Pi (OctoPi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only print from Octoprint, the SD card is not used.